# pythonic way to handle if-else

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Problem:**

I have a very simple problem where I need to update the one date(either origDate or destDate) to another(either origDate or destDate) if anyone out of two is None, Empty or Non-Exists and if both of them do not exists then set both as None.

I am looking for a pythonic way to achieve this. My current code works fine but it is verbose

Example Input:

```
1.    origin_dest_date =  {                        
                            "originDate": "2019-06-30 23:59:00.000",
                            "destDate": None
                        }
2.   origin_dest_date =  {                        
                            "originDate": "2019-06-30 23:59:00.000"
                        }
3.    origin_dest_date =  {                        
                                "originDate": ""
                            }
```

Output:

```
1.  origin_dest_date =  {                        
                                "originDate": "2019-06-30 23:59:00.000",
                                "destDate": "2019-06-30 23:59:00.000"
                            }
2.  origin_dest_date =  {                        
                                "originDate": "2019-06-30 23:59:00.000",
                                "destDate": "2019-06-30 23:59:00.000"
                            }
```

3. origin_dest_date =  {
                               "originDate": None,
                               "destDate": None
                           }

**My Code:**

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

origin_dest_date =  {                        
                        "originDate": "2019-06-30 23:59:00.000",
                        "destDate": None
                    }

isoriginDate = False
isdestDate = False

if 'originDate' in origin_dest_date:    
    isoriginDate = True
    if origin_dest_date['originDate'] is not None and \
        not origin_dest_date['originDate'] == '':
        parse(origin_dest_date['originDate'])
    if origin_dest_date['originDate'] == '':
        origin_dest_date['originDate'] = None
if 'destDate' in origin_dest_date:    
    isdestDate = True        
    if origin_dest_date['destDate'] is not None and \
        not origin_dest_date['destDate'] == '':
        parse(origin_dest_date['destDate'])
    if origin_dest_date['destDate'] == '':
        origin_dest_date['destDate'] = None

if isoriginDate and not isdestDate:
    origin_dest_date['destDate'] = origin_dest_date['originDate']
elif not isoriginDate and isdestDate:
    origin_dest_date['originDate'] = origin_dest_date['destDate']
elif isoriginDate and origin_dest_date['originDate'] is None and \
    isdestDate and \
        origin_dest_date['destDate'] is not None:
    origin_dest_date['originDate'] = origin_dest_date['destDate']
elif isdestDate and \
    origin_dest_date['destDate'] is None and \
        isoriginDate and \
        origin_dest_date['originDate'] is not None:
    origin_dest_date['destDate'] = origin_dest_date['originDate']
elif not isoriginDate and not isdestDate:
    origin_dest_date['originDate'] = None
    origin_dest_date['destDate'] = None

print(origin_dest_date)
```

Comment: `d = odd.get('originDate') or odd.get('destDate'); odd = {'originDate': d, 'destDate': d}`…?

Comment: @deceze But then if both keys exist you'll end up overwriting one.

Comment: @deceze what is this called in Python?

Comment: @Aran I think the spec is unclear on what's supposed to happen in that case…

Comment: @deceze if both available then it should return as it is without over-writing

Comment: @min2bro You mean the `or` operator? It's the `or` operator. It returns the first truthy value.

Comment: Well then be more selective in when you assign. Something like `if not odd.get('originDate'): odd['originDate'] = d`.

Comment: @deceze Can you add your solution as an answer, I want to accept it so that others will be benefited by it

Comment: @deceze if both are empty string then it returns empty, infact I was looking for None

Answer (score 1):

Two main things to improve in your code:

- Use variables to make it look cleaner, especially the conditionals, so you don't repeatedly access the same value in the dictionary;
- Use the dictionary `get` method to lookup a key - it returns its corresponding value if the key exists, if `None` otherwise. Then simply check if the returned value is truthy in Python, which accounts for both `None` and empty strings. `setdefault` may also be used when setting the values at the end.

This is an example of how to implement those things in order to simplify your code:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

origin_dest_date = { "originDate": "2019-06-30 23:59:00.000", "destDate": None }

origin = origin_dest_date.get("originDate")
dest = origin_dest_date.get("destDate")

if origin and not dest:
    origin_dest_date["destDate"] = parse(origin)
elif not origin and dest:
    origin_dest_date["originDate"] = parse(dest)
elif not origin and not dest:
    if origin_dest_date.setdefault("originDate", None) is not None:  # conditional for empty string
        origin_dest_date["originDate"] = None
    if origin_dest_date.setdefault("destDate", None) is not None:  # conditional for empty string
        origin_dest_date["destDate"] = None
```

Comment: Use `if origin is not None and not dest` to make a narrower condition. Otherwise you cannot distinguish between empty string and `None` which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Don't you need to either parse both values or leave both of them as text?

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta OP said to perform the same operation if the values are None or "empty", which I interpreted as being an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt:

```py
def fill_dict(origin_dest_date, key1, key2):
    if not origin_dest_date.get(key1):
        origin_dest_date[key1] = origin_dest_date.get(key2) or None
fill_dict(origin_dest_date, 'destDate', 'originDate')
fill_dict(origin_dest_date, 'originDate', 'destDate')
```

The key idea is:

1. use [dict.get(key)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)
   which will return `None` if the key doesn't exist in the dictionary
2. use loose `if` statement. Empty string or `None` (which is the case if the key doesn't exist in the dictionary) will resolve to `False`.

Comment: `get(key1, None)` could be shortened to `get(key1)`

Comment: I assumed it will raise `KeyError`. Thanks @ababak

Comment: There's one more: `get(key2, None)`

Comment: there were only two use cases when I started writing this code. I made minor change to incorporate the third use case as well.

Answer (score 1):

With a custom function and sample template dict:

```
def arrange_date_keys(d):
    temp = {'originDate': None, 'destDate': None}   # sample dict
    if not d.get('originDate') or not d.get('destDate'):
        date_value = d.get('originDate') or d.get('destDate')
        return temp.fromkeys(temp, date_value)
    return d


origin_dest_date1 = {
    "originDate": "2019-06-30 23:59:00.000",  "destDate": None
}
origin_dest_date2 = {
    "originDate": "2019-06-30 23:59:00.000"
}
origin_dest_date3 = {
    "originDate": ""
}
origin_dest_date4 = {
    "originDate": "2019-06-30 23:59:00.000",  "destDate": "2019-06-30 23:59:00.000"
}

print(arrange_date_keys(origin_dest_date1))
print(arrange_date_keys(origin_dest_date2))
print(arrange_date_keys(origin_dest_date3))
print(arrange_date_keys(origin_dest_date4))
```

The consecutive output:

```
{'originDate': '2019-06-30 23:59:00.000', 'destDate': '2019-06-30 23:59:00.000'}
{'originDate': '2019-06-30 23:59:00.000', 'destDate': '2019-06-30 23:59:00.000'}
{'originDate': None, 'destDate': None}
{'originDate': '2019-06-30 23:59:00.000', 'destDate': '2019-06-30 23:59:00.000'}
```

Comment: It fails when both the dates are available

Comment: @min2bro, that's really simple to fix - see my update

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
>>> def org_dest(d):
      for k,v in d.items():
          date_struc[k]=v
      if all(date_struc.values()):
          pass
      else:
          for k,v in date_struc.items():
              if not v:
                  date_struc[k]= "".join([val for val in date_struc.values() if val])
      return date_struc
```

Final structure with default values as `None` which will be updated by the function.

```
>>> date_struc =  {"originDate": None, "destDate": None}
```

**Test:**

```
>>> date_struc =  {"originDate": None, "destDate": None}

    origin_dest_date_1 =  {"originDate": "2019-06-30 23:59:00.000", "destDate": None}

>>> org_dest(origin_dest_date_1) # test-2 output

    {'originDate': '2019-06-30 23:59:00.000', 'destDate': '2019-06-30 23:59:00.000'}


>>> origin_dest_date_2 =  {"originDate": "2019-06-30 23:59:00.000"}

>>> org_dest(origin_dest_date_2) #test-2 output

{'originDate': '2019-06-30 23:59:00.000', 'destDate': '2019-06-30 23:59:00.000'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:

```
    try:
        if 'destDate' not in origin_dest_date:
            origin_dest_date['destDate'] = origin_dest_date['originDate']
        elif not origin_dest_date['destDate']:
            origin_dest_date['destDate'] = origin_dest_date['originDate']
    except KeyError as e:
        pass
    print(origin_dest_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need this only for two static keys, that you can try this, two line of code

```
 must = {"originDate", "destDate"}
 test = {"originDate":"2019-06-30 23:59:00.000", "destDate": None}
 test.update({key:test[list(test.keys()-key)[0]] for key in must if key not in test or test[key] is None})
```

Tried with one None value :

```
test = {"originDate":"2019-06-30 23:59:00.000", "destDate": None} 
test.update({key:test[list(test.keys()-key)[0]] for key in must if key not in test or test[key] is None}) 
test 
{'originDate': '2019-06-30 23:59:00.000', 'destDate': '2019-06-30 23:59:00.000'}
```

Tried with one key:

```
test = {"originDate":"2019-06-30 23:59:00.000",}
test.update({key:test[list(test.keys()-key)[0]] for key in must if key not in test or test[key] is None})
test
{'originDate': '2019-06-30 23:59:00.000', 'destDate': '2019-06-30 23:59:00.000'}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most accurate solution given by [@deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803219/pythonic-way-to-handle-if-else/57803886#comment102038390_57803219)

```
origin_dest_date =  {                        
                        "originDate": "2019-06-30 23:59:00.000",
                        "destDate": "2019-06-30 23:58:00.000"
                    }

if not origin_dest_date.get('originDate') or not origin_dest_date.get('destDate'): 
    d = (origin_dest_date.get('originDate') or None) or (origin_dest_date.get('destDate') or None)
    origin_dest_date = {'originDate': d, 'destDate': d}

print(origin_dest_date)
```

Comment: `d = origin_dest_date.get('originDate') or origin_dest_date.get('destDate') or None` is sufficient. Also, the duplicate `.get` calls can be avoided.